# Continuity points of cumulative distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $F_n,n\geq 1$ and $F$ cumulative distribution functions and assume that for all $x$ and for arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$, if $n\geq N$, we have
$$
F_n(x-2\varepsilon)-2\varepsilon\leq F(x)\leq F_n(x+2\varepsilon)+2\varepsilon.
$$

Now, let $x^*$ be a continuity point of $F$.

> > Then it is said that
> >     $$
> > \lvert F(x)-F(x^*)\rvert\leq\delta\text{ if }\lvert x-x^*\rvert\leq 2\varepsilon.
> > $$

I do not see this implication. Why does this follow from our assumption? Or maybe we do not even need the assumption?

I think, we do not need the assumption:

Let $\delta\geq 0$. Since $F$ is continuous in $x^*$ there exists some $\delta'\geq 0$ such that $\lvert F(x)-F(x^*)\rvert\leq\delta$ if $\lvert x-x^*\rvert\leq\delta'$.

In case $\delta'=2\varepsilon$, everything is okay.
In case $\delta'>2\varepsilon$ the statement is true also.
In case $\delta'<2\varepsilon$, we have that $\lvert F(x)-F(x^*)\leq\delta$ if $\lvert x-x^*\rvert\leq\delta' <2\varepsilon$.

So, all in all, the statement should hold.

Comment: Is there any assumed connection between $F_n$ and $F$? Like, does $F_n\to F$ pointwise?

Comment: No, on the contrary, from the assumption the aim is to show that $F_n\to F$ pointwise for all continuity points of $F$.

Comment: Okay, looking more closely at this, it seems clear that some statements have gotten garbled. Surely, the assumption should be saying that for any $\epsilon>0$ *there exists* some $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, … Further, in the stated conclusion, there is this $\delta$ which is mentioned nowhere else. If the intent is to say that for any $\delta>0$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ so that the stated inequality holds, that is just a slightly unusual way to state the continuity of $F$ at $x^*$. But as it stands, it looks a bit odd.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. The $N$ and the $\delta$ seem to fall from the sky without any reasoning.  - So you would agree that we do not need the assumption to say that - if $F$ is continuous in $x^*$ that for arbitrary $\delta>0$ we have that $\lvert F(x)-F(x^*)\rvert\leq\delta$ if $\lvert x-x^*\rvert\leq 2\varepsilon$ (where at least the $\varepsilon$ seems to come from the assumption)?